# How to load Struts2 MessageResources.properties file into non-action classes

Tags: java, struts2, quartz-scheduler

How to load Struts2 `MessageResources.properties` into other non-action class. Basically the requirement is i have a Quartz scheduler `Servlet` and a job class within a struts2 web application. I want to get the properties of `MessageResource.properties` into this servlet/job class. But i am unable to read the file.

Comment: i believe something like this will read the property file in your class path `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("prproperty file");`

Comment: you are a life Savior for me at this minute..  Thanx a ton..:)

Comment: if you are already using Apache common i suggest to take a look what suggested by Chin as that is much more flexible and elegant approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache Commons Configurations library is what you are looking for. :)

Comment: Is it possible to use the same approach for hibernate.cfg.xml as well.  i tried using XMLConfiguration but isn't working.The code is -            XMLConfiguration xmlConfiguration = new XMLConfiguration("hibernate.cfg.xml");  
            System.out.println(xmlConfiguration.getProperty("hibernate.connection.url"));
            System.out.println(xmlConfiguration.getProperty("session-factory.hibernate.connection.username"));
            System.out.println(xmlConfiguration.getProperty("hibernate-configuration.session-factory.hibernate.connection.password")); //all returns null value

Comment: Yes it is possible. Did you check whether the hibernate configuration descriptor file, "hibernate.cfg.xml" is in the same directory of the class, or in the classpath? Check this for an explanation: http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_filebased.html

Comment: Tried this with the links you provided.   XMLConfiguration xmlConfiguration = new XMLConfiguration("hibernate.cfg.xml");
            xmlConfiguration.getString("hibernate.connection.url");
            xmlConfiguration.getProperty("hibernate.connection.url");
            SubnodeConfiguration configurationAt = xmlConfiguration.configurationAt("session-factory");
            configurationAt.getProperty(hibernateConnectionUrl);
            String rootElementName = xmlConfiguration.getRootElementName();

Comment: I am getting the result for rootElementName,  but rest am unable to. Any help would be appreciated.